# Turn the last paragraph of one style into another style, ms-word, VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

This code allows to change **all** text with style "myStyleOne" for "myStyleTwo".

```
Option Explicit
Sub replaceStyleForAnotherStyle()
Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("myStyleOne")
Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
Selection.Find.Replacement.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("myStyleTwo")
With Selection.Find
    .Text = ""
    .Replacement.Text = ""
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
    .MatchWholeWord = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .MatchSoundsLike = False
    .MatchAllWordForms = False
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End Sub
```

What should the code look like if I want to turn only **the last paragraph** of "myStyleOne" into "myStyleTwo"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the last paragraph with a given style:

```
Function lastOfStyle(st As String) As Paragraph
    For i = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count To 1 Step -1
        If ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Style = st Then
            Set lastOfStyle = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Now you can change the style with this simple statement:

```
lastOfStyle("MyStyle1").Style = "MyStyle2"
```

But if you want to do it in your macro, for other reasons that I missed, then you should add the following at the beginning of your macro:

```
Dim p as Paragraph: Set p = lastOfStyle("Normal")
if p Is Nothing then Exit Sub
p.Range.Select
```

Then set `.Wrap = wdFindStop` in the `With Selection.Find` bloc instead of  * .Wrap = wdFindContinue *

Comment: Thank you. I've rewritten it, however now it finds the last paragraph in text, not the last paragraph of "myStyleOne"...
The code is here: [http://codepad.org/WqpN0AUx](http://codepad.org/WqpN0AUx).

Or does it mean that the code has to contain a loop to find the last paragraph of "myStyleOne"..? If so, what should it look like then..?

Comment: @Zolvas yes it has to be a simple loop, I added it to my edited answer. But as you can see, if it is only a matter of changing the style of this found paragraph, it can be done with a single statement.

Comment: Thank you! 1) In the function: But I think you should replace "Paragraphs.Count" for `ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count` and "If Paragraphs(i).Style" for `If ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Style`. Otherwise it resolves an  error; 2) In the second block of code: "= ("MyStyle2")" should also be replaced for `= "MyStyle2"`, i.e. without brackets, for the same reason.
It would be great if you consider improving the answer in this manner. Then I will tick this answer as the most helpful and will show my bunch of code which also might once be useful for someone...

Comment: @ZolVas Hi again :) & Thanks. I made the suggested edits. I am glad to know that your problem was solved. By the way i did not put ActiveDocument because I  though that the macro was to be a member of the document itself.

Answer (score -1):

Have you seen this answer? It really helps: **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32957672/5410914)**. The things you might know: in VBA there are subroutines (sub) and functions. Functions can be used in many subroutines and should go separately.

Great. You want to **copy** and use the code? Here you are, just copy it all to the developer tab on the ribbon: **http://codepad.org/Wd5Rer4y**. Then you can run **sub** `replaceStyleForAnotherStyleSimple()` or **sub** `replaceStyleForAnotherStyleComplicated()`. Both of them rely on **function** `lastOfStyle`. Click alt+f8 and choose wisely.

Great. But is it possible to do the same thing without function?
Sure! Here it comes! `replaceStyleForAnotherStyleNoFunction()`

```
Sub replaceStyleForAnotherStyleNoFunction()
    Dim parCountDown, i, sMyPar
    parCountDown = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count
    For i = parCountDown To 1 Step -1
        If ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Style = "myStyleOne" Then 'change the part for: "Normal"
            ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Style = "myStyleTwo" 'change the part for: "Heading 1"
            'sMyPar = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.Text
            'MsgBox (sMyPar) 'message box with that paragraph
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

So you see here three ways to do the same thing and easy path to copy all that. Stay tuned and Good luck!